# custom plugin not showing - ImportError: No module named resources

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I just develop a custom plugin in QGIS. It folder located here

> C:\Users(user).qgis2\python\Plugins\PluginTest

But it is not showing the plugin in QGIS, although a downloaded plugin VectorCompare showing correctly in plugin dropdown. I have no warning or error log.
I just saw an error in Plugin > Installed tab.

Couldn't load plugin TaskAutomation due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

```
>     ImportError: No module named resources 
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "E:/QGISSE~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 306, in startPlugin
>         plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>       File "C:/Users/FK/.qgis2/python/plugins\TaskAutomation\__init__.py", line 34, in
> classFactory
>         from .TLL_Task import TaskAutomation
>       File "E:/QGISSE~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
>         mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>       File "C:/Users/FK/.qgis2/python/plugins\TaskAutomation\TLL_Task.py", line 26, in 
>         import resources
>       File "E:/QGISSE~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
>         mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     ImportError: No module named resources
```

Comment: Try running this: `pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run this command in my qgis plugin through OSGeo4W to resolve this error

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

Complete command run on **OSGeo4W Shell**

```
C:\Users\[your user name]\.qgis2\python\Plugins\PluginTest pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

[**QGIS Doucmentation provided the details**](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html)

Comment: I was running in the system command prompt; I had to go to the OSGeo4W shell to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the plugin category it might be available from another drop down menu, e.g. 'Web' or 'Vector'.

Have you also checked the 'Manage and Install plugins' dialog? If this does not help you, please provide more information. Did you build it using the Plugin Builder plugin?

Comment: question updated

Comment: Maybe rebuild resources using the OSGeo4W Shell? Seems related to [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/qgis-plugin-problems-importing-resources-resources-rc-file-plugin-doasnt-l)

Comment: make command is not working

Comment: Try 'make clear' and then 'make deploy'. Do you have the resources.py file? Maybe it needs fixing...

Comment: where to check resource file

Comment: Sorry I mean the Makefile. Else I don't know...