# Image Adding Problem to QGIS Plugin GUI with Qt Designer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt, gui, qt-designer

I'm using QGIS 3.1 and I created a plugin. Finally, I want to add a image(.png) to my plugin's GUI with Qt Designer. But when I add it, QGIS gives an error when it opens and my plugin does not work.

These is my steps:

- First, I open my "...base.ui" file with Qt Designer and I create a empty label
  [image]
- Image source selection with pixmap
  [image]

  [image]
- Scale to image and saving after that
  [image]

------- Errors --------------
[image]

--- My compile.bat and recources.qrc files ----
[image]
[image]

**Edit:**
---Error Messages as text format---

```
Couldn't load plugin 'save_attributes' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, bytes, bytes, bytes): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str' 

(Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.10.3-A Coruña A Coruña, 0e1f846438 )
```

Note: Maybe the method that I applied was wrong. I can try to image adding with different way, if you tell me.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I edited my post and added errors as text format on last part.

Comment: Did you try choosing the image with "choose file" instead of "choose resource" ?

Comment: @JULESG yes I tried and this way, it does not give an error and plugin is working. but the image does not appear on the GUI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution with the help of [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/qgis-plugin-problems-importing-resources-resources-rc-file-plugin-doesnt-l).

It worked for me. I'm on QGis 3.16, I hope it's the same for the 3.10 version.

Once you've added the resource image. You need to open the file `save_attributes_dialog_base.ui` with a text editor and look for a `ressources` element. Like this one :

[image]

This is the cause of the problem. You have to empty the element. Like this :

[image]

Save your file. Go to QGis, refresh your plugin and you're good !

Comment: I tried to your solution. no longer gives an error, my plugin opens. but the image is not appear where I put on the GUI.

     ss: https://i.ibb.co/hcsFb0r/Screenshot-5.png

Comment: @AFK Did you try to put another image ? maybe with another format ?

Comment: no but it works now. I rerun again my compile.bat file and tried again to your solution, finally it works. thnx