# 'ImportError: No module named resources_rc' while adding image in custom plugin using Qt designer

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, qt

I am trying to add an image in the UI file of my custom plugin which will be used in QGIS.
But I am facing this error:
**ImportError: No module named resources_rc**

Could anyone tell me how to add an image in the plugin?

I even tried doing this :
[QGIS plugin: Problems importing resources (resources_rc) file - plugin doesn't load - PATH problems?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/qgis-plugin-problems-importing-resources-resources-rc-file-plugin-doesnt-l)  but it doesnt work.

Comment: It seems like you should have a file called `resource.qrc`, and after it should be converted with the `.py` extension, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301204/importerror-no-module-named-resource-rc